# Displaying a JPG stored in memory (not in disks) using Qt?

Tags: qt

I read a YUV file from `/dev/fb0` and transcode into a JPG stored in memory. I want to use Qt to display it, but the `QImage` class loads JPG files stored on disk with for example  `load("a.jpg")`.

But I just want to display it once, so I don't want to save the file to disk, and then use the `QImage` class load it from disk, and finally display it. It's so inefficient.

How can I create the image directly from memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `QImage::loadFromData` for that.